# "we only have 67 percent of the population vaccinated"

Tags: causative-have

> "we only have 67 percent of the population vaccinated"

I am wondering what construction is this? Is this To have sb done or what?

Comment: The text is ambiguous. You could parse it as *[Our policy is that] we **require / cause / implement** a 67% vaccination rate*, OR a simple assertion that *The vaccination rate [which we have] **is** 67%*

Comment: Can anyone give the name of this structure? I've never noted it before

Answer (score 2):

The structure is *[ "have" + object + modifier ]*. It roughly means, "We have a situation where X is Y", and it usually has a negative meaning. The modifier can be just about anything that modifies X.

Here's some examples of the structure with different modifiers:

> We have two of our three children **angry at us**. (plain adjective)
> We have two of our three children **living in our basement**. (present participle)
> We have two of our three children **not talking to us**. (negated present participle)
> We have two of our three children **in prison**. (prepositional phrase)

In all cases, the sentence means, "*Two of our three children are [bold part].*" There's no causation or passive or anything else like that.

Comment: It has been argued that this construction is actually the origin of the perfect construction in English and other languages: _I have the book written_, exactly like gotube's examples -> _I have written the book_, with my explicit agency.

Comment: Indeed.  It meant "I have (=possess) the book, which I have written."  The construction was later generalized to allow, e.g., "I have lost the book", in which "have" doesn't indicate posession.

Answer (score 0):

(we only have 67 percent of the population vaccinated=We only have vaccinated 67 percent of the population.)

Both are same in meaning, **vaccinate** is a transitive verb, so it require direct object(67 percent of the population)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what the structure is